# Spring Roo 1.1.0.M1 .jspx rewriting

Tags: spring-roo, jspx

I am attempting to customize a create.jspx in Roo 1.1.0.M1. I am removing some fields from the UI that I want to automatically set in the controller (eg. dateCreated, createdBy).

This works ok, UNTIL I edit the entity java file in any way. Roo then proceeds to rewrite my create.jspx back to the way it used to be

There is no automaticallyMaintainView=false option in 1.1.0.M1, so my question is: How do I get Roo to leave my .jspxs alone? I am at the stage where I want full control and don't want Roo changing them any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set "z" attribute to "user-managed" and "render" attribute to "false" so Spring Roo leaves it alone.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/index.html#d4e1544

or in controller change `RooWebScaffold(automaticallyMaintainView=false)`

Answer (score 1):

Since Roo 1.1.0.x Roo offers complete round tripping of your jspx view resources which makes the need for automaticallyMaintainView flag obsolete. Roo will not delete any changes you add to your jspx file.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?91086-1-1-0-M1-problem-with-generated-controller-automaticallyMaintainView-true&p=310804#post310804